# No ManagedConnections available

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

we have started facing a very strange issue recently on production, this issue occurs only on Monday's between 8:30AM t0 9:30 AM

The inUseConnections count goes to become 20 in no time and application hangs and we have to flush the connections to get it back to working.

the error seen in the logs is:

```
2016-05-16 09:18:31,156 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ); - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ))
2016-05-16 09:18:31,156 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener] Error performing load command
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3048)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:815)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor205.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:357)
    at $Proxy186.find(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor205.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:194)
    at $Proxy186.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.baad.merc.service.proposal.impl.ProposalServiceImpl.retrieveProposalSummary(ProposalServiceImpl.java:1050)
    at com.baad.merc.service.proposal.impl.ProposalServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3c98e9c0.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:77)
    at com.baad.merc.service.support.client.spring.aop.ServiceMethodAspect.serviceMethod(ServiceMethodAspect.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor214.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
    at com.baad.merc.service.proposal.impl.ProposalServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dfbf2a28.retrieveProposalSummary(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor297.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy198.retrieveProposalSummary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1303.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ); - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:96)
    at com.baad.merc.component.datasource.impl.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:35)
    at com.baad.merc.component.datasource.impl.TrackingDataSource.getConnection(TrackingDataSource.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] )
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:301)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:538)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:348)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:330)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:403)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:850)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:90)
    ... 95 more
```

Could you please help me understand what could be the reason behind this and how can this be resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Note: we haven't seen this issue before in our application, it was working fine for many years, all the connections in the application are being closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its hard to point the exact reason without knowing your business flows.

I think that if you're running out of available connections, obviously someone consumes them.

In general it can be:

**Option 1:**
The same code, called simultaneously. For example, in the provided stack trace I see:

```
com.baad.merc.service.proposal.impl.ProposalServiceImpl.retrieveProposalSummary(ProposalServiceImpl.java:1050)
```

I would check that, by placing some counter/metric. Since you're using AOP, it shouldn't be hard to implement as an aspect or something.

**Option 2:**
There are just too many users using your application at that period of time, so they run their requests. This also can be tracked like this: when you reach, say, 19 connections (again you can use counter for measuring that) - just create a thread dump programmatically and store it in some place on the filesystem. So you'll be able to track the flow that actually caused this situation.

Similarly it can be even some internal activity, for instance a scheduled job or something.

Comment: Thanks Mark for reply, we have already placed a script in place to take thread dumps when connections start increasing and it hasn't helped as cause of error is not always the same (not always retrieveProposalSummary method is causing this). let's say it's being caused by the no. of users do you think increasing the number of connections by 5 in ds file would help?

Comment: Its a kind of number hacking. If you have 20 users working simultaneously its possible that tomorrow 25 users will connect and consume db connections. Of course if can be temporary solution for now, but I would better thought about future. Maybe you can optimize the query so that the DB access won't last that long, so the probability to occupy connections will decrease. Maybe it worth to put the db queries into some queue. So that they will be processed asynchronously. Maybe you should consider using asynchronous IO at the web layer. A lot of options are available actually.... Hope this helps